# Running a Gallery after Loading Screen Completes loading

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am currently new to Android. I have seen many cases whereby a loading screen is able to initiate the downloading of files. I would like to know how is it possible for me to initiate the gallery on the postexecute() command when the loading screen has finished processing its background task. 
The following is the code in the background task. Am i suppose to write codes inside this background for the gallery to execute on the postexecute() or is there any way else i can do this.

P.S My Loading screen and the gallery are on different java files. So is there any way i can allow the gallery to run right after the loading screen on the postexecute command?

Thanks

```
  //The code to be executed in a background thread.
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) 
            {
                /* This is just a code that delays the thread execution 4 times, 
                 * during 850 milliseconds and updates the current progress. This 
                 * is where the code that is going to be executed on a background
                 * thread must be placed. 
                 */
                try 
                {
                    //Get the current thread's token
                    synchronized (this) 
                    {
                        //Initialize an integer (that will act as a counter) to zero
                        int counter = 0;
                        //While the counter is smaller than four
                        while(counter <= 4)
                        {
                            //Wait 850 milliseconds
                            this.wait(850);
                            //Increment the counter 
                            counter++;
                            //Set the current progress. 
                            //This value is going to be passed to the onProgressUpdate() method.
                            publishProgress(counter*25);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            //Update the TextView and the progress at progress bar
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
            {
                //Update the progress at the UI if progress value is smaller than 100
                if(values[0] <= 100)
                {
                    tv_progress.setText("Progress: " + Integer.toString(values[0]) + "%");
                    pb_progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Simply launch the gallery from PostExecute.

```
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void...values) 
        {
            //get image path
            File file = <imageFilepath>;
             //add to intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //start activity
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: I have actually tried this method but it still gives me a black screen. Any suggestions of codes for the //launch gallery intent here  such that i can launch it?